# Dynamically selecting fields in a linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a linq query where I’d like to dynamically select only the fields requested by my user.

Currently I’m mapping my Jobs to a data transformation object like this:

```
var jobs = (from p in jobsDB
select new JobReportDTO()
{
    JobID = p.JobID,
    EventType = p.EventType,
    DateApproved = p.ApprovedDate,
    DateEntered = p.EnteredDate,
    DateClosed = p.ClosedDate,
    StartDate = p.StartDate,
    FinishDate = p.FinishDate,
    InsuredName = p.InsuredName,
    StreetAddress = p.StreetAddress,
    Suburb = p.Suburb,
    State = p.State,
    Postcode = p.Postcode,
    .... etc
```

Within this function I have a number of boolean variables that identify whether that field should be sent to the view, i.e.:

```
public bool ShowInsuredName { get; set; }
public bool ShowSuburb { get; set; }
public bool ShowICLA { get; set; }
public bool ShowClaimNumber { get; set; }
public bool ShowFileMananger { get; set; }
public bool ShowSupervisor { get; set; }
public bool ShowStatus { get; set; }
... etc
```

How can I modify my linq query to show selected fields only?

I’ve tried

```
var jobs = (from p in jobsDB
    select new JobReportDTO()
    {
        JobID = p.JobID,
        jobReport.ShowEventType == true ? EventType = p.EventType : "",
        ... etc
```

But am getting “invalid initialiser member declarator”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
EventType = jobReport.ShowEventType == true ? p.EventType : string.Empty,
```

Comment: To my understanding he doesn't want `EventType` to be part of his object when the corresponding `bool` is false

Comment: @AlexanderDerck JobReportDTO is already a property/field. He can set it to null otherwise

Comment: I know but "How can I modify my linq query to show selected fields only?" just sounds like he wants an object with only certain properties.

Comment: This was perfect, thanks, I can work with a null object (as opposed to the property totally missing)

Answer (score 2):

If you can afford LINQ method syntax and use strong naming convention for options like `public bool Show{DTOPropertyName} { get; set; }`, then you can make your life much easier with the help of the `System.Linq.Expressions` and the following little helper method

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector, object options)
    {
        var memberInit = (MemberInitExpression)selector.Body;
        var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
        foreach (var binding in memberInit.Bindings)
        {
            var option = options.GetType().GetProperty("Show" + binding.Member.Name);
            if (option == null || (bool)option.GetValue(options)) bindings.Add(binding);
        }
        var newSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(memberInit.NewExpression, bindings), selector.Parameters);
        return source.Select(newSelector);
    }
}
```

What it does is to remove the assignments which has associated `ShowProperty` with value set to `false`.

The usage is simple

```
var jobs = jobsDB.Select(p => new JobReportDTO
{
    JobID = p.JobID,
    EventType = p.EventType,
    DateApproved = p.ApprovedDate,
    DateEntered = p.EnteredDate,
    DateClosed = p.ClosedDate,
    StartDate = p.StartDate,
    FinishDate = p.FinishDate,
    InsuredName = p.InsuredName,
    StreetAddress = p.StreetAddress,
    Suburb = p.Suburb,
    State = p.State,
    Postcode = p.Postcode,
    .... etc 
}, jobReport);
```

If you set a breakpoint in the debugger and examine the `newSelector` variable, you'll see that only properties that do not have `ShowProperty` (like `JobID`) or have `ShowProperty = true` are included.

Comment: This would only fetch the required records from the database right?

Comment: It's just a `Select` part and controls the fetched **fields** (columns). What about records, it would fetch what you specify in `Where` clause if you have so.

Comment: yeh sorry I meant columns :)

Comment: No problem, so yes then :)

Comment: Assuming using EF, you can add `var sql = jobs.ToString();` and see the actual SQL query.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful