# Dynamically selecting fields in a linq subquery

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to dynamically filter the fields in a select clause similar to what was requested by a user as was described in the post [dynamically selecting fields in a linq query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752784/dynamically-selecting-fields-in-a-linq-query). (I describe my problem and fully below so you don't need to go to the link)

What I am trying to do in short is to define a query and then at runtime determine what fields are part of the select statement and which are filterd out.

```
QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter {
    ShowClientInfo = false,
    ShowPackaging = true,
    ShowName = true,
    ShowWeight = false
};

//Below is a sample linq query that works without desired filtering.
// Comments are to the right of the fields I want filterd with the object above
var testQuery = db.Client
                  .Where(c => c.ID == clientId)
                  .Select(c =>
                   new 
                   {
                       ClientInfo = c,               // <== Supress this
                       Packaging = c.ClientPackaging // <== Show this
                                    .Where(cp => !cp.IsDeleted)
                                    .Select(cp =>
                                     new
                                     {
                                         Name = cp.Name,    // <== Show this
                                         Weight = cp.Weight // <== Suppress this
                                     }
                                    ).ToList()
                   }
                  ).FirstOrDefault();
```

The first answer of the related question was not sufficient, so I am not going to go into it further. It is insufficient because the linq statement would still query the database for specific fields, and would only just not assign the value on return.

The second awesome answer by Ivan Stoev is what I am trying to have expanded upon. This answer prevents the fields from even being part of the query to the database and is preferred.  But this only works for the outermost select of the linq query.  The part I am having trouble with is creating a helper method that will work on subqueries in the select statement.

The reason for the trouble, is the first use of the overload is of type IQueryable, the nested queries in the select are of type IEnumerable and thus will not map to the current extension of the answer.

Extension from [other post mentioned above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752784/dynamically-selecting-fields-in-a-linq-query) that works for the outermost select statement

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> selector, object options)
    {
        var memberInit = (MemberInitExpression)selector.Body;
        var bindings = new List<MemberBinding>();
        foreach (var binding in memberInit.Bindings)
        {
            var option = options.GetType().GetProperty("Show" + binding.Member.Name);
            if (option == null || (bool)option.GetValue(options)) bindings.Add(binding);
        }
        var newSelector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(
            Expression.MemberInit(memberInit.NewExpression, bindings), selector.Parameters);
        return source.Select(newSelector);
    }
}
```

Here is my sample query that works with the first Select, but the nested select statements do NOT work as they need to be an IEnumerable extension.

```
public class QueryFilter
{
  public bool ShowClientInfo {get;set;}
  public bool ShowPackaging {get;set;}
  public bool ShowName {get;set;}
  public bool ShowWeight {get;set;}
} 

QueryFilter filter = new QueryFilter {
    ShowClientInfo = false,
    ShowPackaging = true,
    ShowName = true,
    ShowWeight = false
};

var testQuery = db.Client
                  .Where(c => c.ID == clientId)
                  .Select(c =>
                   new 
                   {
                       ClientInfo = c,
                       Packaging = c.ClientPackaging
                                    .Where(cp => !cp.IsDeleted)
                                    .Select(cp => // <==== This select does not work
                                     new
                                     {
                                         Name = cp.Name,
                                         Weight = cp.Weight,
                                         packages = cp.ShipmentPackage
                                                      .Select(sp => // <==== Neither does this
                                                       new 
                                                       {
                                                           Dimension_x = sp.Dimension_x,
                                                           Dimension_y = sp.Dimension_y,
                                                           Dimension_z = sp.Dimension_z
                                                       }, filter //<== additional filter parameter for the select statement
                                                      ).ToList()
                                     }, filter //<== additional filter parameter for the select statement
                                    ).ToList()
                   }, filter //<== additional filter parameter for the select statement
                   ).FirstOrDefault();
```

The error I am getting on the two nested queries in the .Select is:

> Method 'Select' has 1 parameter(s) but is invoked with 2 argument(s)

I need to create an IEnumerable version of the method that would work in this case.

How would I create the method as an IEnumerable?

Comment: `select` will return 1 data type, but you have define `select(c => <new list>, filter)`, did you have something missed?

Comment: As for answers, references to other pages should be additional informations, not essential. Most people won't bother navigating through all your links.

Comment: I added the links so you could see what my source was and what research I did BEFORE posting this question.  ALL code and information relative to this question is posted IN the question, not in the link. @Kilazur please don't down vote because you did not read the question.

Comment: @Alex, The select(c => <new list>, filter) is a call to the MyExtensions.Select defined above.  It does take an additional parameter of type List<string> filter. I will alter the 2nd set of code to include the definition of that additional parameter that is passed into the extension method.

Comment: Sorry... to clarify the comment above....  The Select method does take an additional parameter. My question is still, how do I change the Extension method as an IEnumerable so Linq will recognize it in the subqueries.

Comment: @Kilazur I have reworked the question based on what you said to eliminate any ambiguity or need to think you need to go to the other post.